# php nearest ten-th value

Tags: php

I am getting a max value through value. It can be any digit (whole number). I want it to take to next tenth-value, using PHP

Example:

If value is 66, then I need value 70
If value is 6, then I need value 10
If value is 98, then I need value 100

Comment: At least this is a math problem *worth thinking about*.

Comment: digit is not a synonym for whole number, although a digit is a whole number. There are only ten digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: if the value is 11, would you need 10 or 20?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an arithmetic problem:

```
y = ceil(x / 10) * 10
```

If you’re looking just for the nearest decade, use `round` instead.

Comment: maybe 10 * ceil($x/10) is better ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: Title says nearest but text says next.

Comment: ceil round up the value to next highest integer

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 66;

    $val = ceil($num / 10) * 10;

echo $val;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
echo round(66,-1);
```

---

up to 30 characters