# convert a number to the next 10,20,30 and so on

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php nearest ten-th value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375636/php-nearest-ten-th-value)

i want a function simillar to [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) but to get the next 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 number

example:

```
$x = 5;
echo theunction($x);
```

returns 10 and if `$x = 15.5;` it should returns 20 and so on

Comment: You could just divide by 10, round, and then multiply?

Answer (score 3):

Simply Try

```
$x = ceil($x/10) * 10;
```